# Need some help with Sql Server and a simple Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I wish to make a trigger but i'm not sure how to grab the data for whatever caused the trigger.

I have a simlpe table.

```
FooId INT PK NOT NULL IDENTITY
Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
```

I wish to have a trigger so that when an UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE occurs, i then do the following.

#### Pseduocode

```
IF INSERT
    Print 'Insert' & Name
ELSE IF UPDATE
    Print 'Update' & FooId & Name
ELSE IF DELETE
    Print 'Delete' & FooId & Name
```

Now, I know how to make a trigger for a table.
What i don't know how to do is figure out the values based on what the trigger type is.

Can anyone help?

#### Edit: Not sure if it helps, but db is Sql Server 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the pseudo table "inserted" contains the new data, and "deleted" table contains the old data.

You can do something like

```
create trigger mytrigger on mytable for insert, update, delete
as
    if ( select count(*) from inserted ) > 0
        -- insert or update
        select FooId, Name from inserted
    else
        -- delete
        select FooId, Name from deleted
```

To clarify all the comments made by others, on an insert, the *inserted* table contains data and *deleted* is empty.  On a delete, the situation is reversed.  On an update, *deleted* and *inserted* contain the "before" and "after" copy of any updated rows.

Comment: Does the INSERTED table contain the identity value IF the action is an INSERT?

Comment: Yes it will.  It will contain all data in the inserted rows, except text or binary columns.

Comment: But you are not considering the new MERGE command in your logic.

Comment: SO, if i do an insert, then the inserted table has data, deleted has none. If i do an update, BOTH inserted and deleted table have data? And if i do a Deleted, then inserted table is empty and deleted table has data?

Comment: that's correct.  Think of "before" and "after".  On an update the inserted and deleted contain the contents of each row before and after the update.  On an insert, there is no "before", the row wasn't there.  On a delete there is no "after" the row is now gone.

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing a trigger, you have to account for the fact that your trigger may be called by a statement that effects more than one row at a time.

As others have pointed out, you reference the **inserted** table to get the values of new values of updated or inserted rows, and you reference the deleted table to get the value of **deleted** rows.

Comment: AHH! I missed the comment about the INSERTED table is for both INSERT and UPDATE trigger types. Cheers for the clarification.

Comment: and if you are looking for differences in an update, you compare inserted to deleted

Comment: nope, i'm just wanting to know when a table has been (insert or update) OR (deleted). if insert or update, do stuff #1. else do stuff #2.

Answer (score 0):

SQL triggers provide an implicitly-defined table called "inserted" which returns the affected rows, allowing you to do things like

```
UPDATE mytable SET mytimestamp = GETDATE() WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM inserted)
```

Regarding your code sample, you'll want to create separate INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE triggers if you are performing separate actions for each.

(At least, this is the case in SQL Server... you didn't specify a platform.)

Comment: I don't need to make seperate triggers .. well at least with MS Sql Server. u can have 1, 2 or 3 tryigger types, for a single trigger. MikeW has demostrated this in his reply (in this thread).

Answer (score 0):

On 2008, there is also MERGE command. How do you want to handle it?

Starting from 2008, there are four commands you can modify a table with: 
INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and MERGE:

http://blogs.conchango.com/davidportas/archive/2007/11/14/SQL-Server-2008-MERGE.aspx

http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/grumpyolddba/archive/2009/03/11/reasons-to-move-to-sql-2008-merge.aspx

What do you want your trigger to do when someone issues a MERGE command against your table?

Comment: ????? can u please elaborate how to use this, with regards to the example code in the opening post?

Comment: No idea.. i still need to get my head around what that new command, is. :(